# Ubuntu 14 wget issue

Tags: apt

Whenever I try to wget http://media.steampowered.com/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz I get an error that the server was unable to resolve hostname. Any solutions for this?

Comment: Can you download it with other things? Firefox? Or `curl`, if you have it installed?

Comment: whats the output of `host media.steampowered.com`?

Comment: Or try `ping -c 4 media.steampowered.com` or if it fails `nslookup media.steampowered.com` or if that also fails `nslookup media.steampowered.com 8.8.8.8`? At least the last command should definitely give an output without errors if it is a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the same command again. It may have been a temporary problem with your DNS server and/or their domain name registration that has been fixed now. I just tried it and successfully downloaded the whole 3,170,982 bytes of it.

**Edit**

If your DNS server still has problems try using the Google provided one. Edit your `/etc/resolv.conf` (as a root) and put there this single line:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

then try again.

Comment: Same error, I assume its my server. Host support seems to think its not though. I cant actually apt-get update or wget anything